# Expressjs MVC can't get listAll() to return data from mongoose while in router

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller, promise

I'm trying to implement MVC(ish) architecture for a very specific use-case , into expressjs.
I think I'm having a promise issue but I'm still not able to correctly debug the problem here.

So about the architecture :
Router calls will trigger functions that are in fact methods of classes in a service layer.
ex: router.get('/users/list') -triggers-> userService.listAll() -returns array of users->res.render('apage',{users:users}); (users being a variable containing the returned values)..

While the userService is able to access the datasource and return the data , nothing is being affected to the "users" variable inside the router.

actual code is :
users.js

```
router.get('/dashboard',  function(req, res) {
    var users= userService.listAll();
    res.render('dashboard.twig', {users: users});
});
```

UserService.js

```
async listAll(){

        await utilisateurModel.find({}).then(
            function(data){
            console.log("data is:"+JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;

     });
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: can you please help This is quite urgent thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get many mistake about Promise and `async/await`.

`listAll` is a async function, you have to use `await` keyword to "get" the value.

UserService.js

```
async listAll() {
  const data = await utilisateurModel.find({});
  console.log("data is:" + JSON.stringify(data));
  return data;
}
```

users.js

```
router.get('/dashboard', async function (req, res) { // async function
  var users = await userService.listAll(); // await keyword
  res.render('dashboard.twig', { users: users });
});
```

Comment: Actually it's not the root of the problem ,although you're probably right even that find is already async by default (the .then testifies) however it was a twigjs issue .

Thanks .